# Azure devops .netcore fails but builds fine in visual studio

Tags: azure-devops, azure-deployment

--Fixed it... Geez this stuff is Janky.
Microsoft link to explain what to do
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

I had to remove the version tag from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All references in the csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" **DELETE Version Version="2.2.0" />
```

--Edit 12/4
I I installed on my PC .netcore to 2.2, Now it fails the same. I didn't change a setting in my Project. I am specifying in my project settings to use 2.1 not 2.2. 
It appears in the YAML where i set the .netcore version is not applying.

```
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core Tool Installer'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.500
```

I am not sure what to do now.

--
I get following error when building in azure devops or publish from VS to an Azure app service. Visual Studio builds it fine.

> (Restore target) -> 2018-12-04T01:30:44.4900171Z
>   D:\a\1\s\cbw.services\cbw.mvc.services.csproj : error NU1202: Package
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1
>   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0
>   supports: netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2)

My Build YAML

```
resources:
- repo: self
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core Tool Installer'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.500
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.9.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.9.1
#- task: NuGetCommand@2
#  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
#  inputs:
#    restoreSolution: '***.sln'
#    feedsToUse: config
#    nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
#    externalFeedCredentials: <Name of the NuGet service connection>
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.config
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
#- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
#  displayName: Publish
#  inputs:
#    command: publish
#    publishWebProjects: True
#    arguments: 'release --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: True
    projects:  '**/*.sln'
    arguments: release -o $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
    zipAfterPublish: True
    modifyOutputPath: false
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure CBW Dev'
    WebAppName: 'cbwServicesDev'
    Package: $(System.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip
```

Comment: the error suggests you need dotnet core 2.2 (not 2.1) on the build agent?

Comment: It looks like Asp Net Core 2.2.0 has alreade released in nuget. But .NET Core 2.2 has not yet released officially...

Comment: @Aries I seem to recall they did the exact same thing for ASP.NET Core 2.1!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the .NET Core SDK installer task to your build.

Edit: It needs to be the first task, or at least before any build task.

A good [post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AzureDevOpsContinuousBuildDeployTestWithASPNETCore22PreviewInOneHour.aspx) by Scott Hanselman walks you through this problem.

[image]

[image]